# Socket sends but does not receive in emulator

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I am making an app which two devices should communicate through TCP sockets. one device is my samsung phone and the other is emulator. I set the emulator to be the client and my phone the server. the client connects to the phone and works fine (sends and receives) but after some minutes it stops receiving but sending has no problem. The networking part has hundreds of lines of code with many functions which make it complicated to read so I decided not to write it here but I suspect that the problem is from the emulator itself. meaning if I use a real device instead of emulator this won't happen. much parts of networking codes are similar for server and client and the server runs normally. only the client socket in emulator stops RECEIVING. It can send (so the connection is alive) And I check the threads. They are alive too. Do you agree that this might be the emulator's problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem in your application and not in the emulator, because:

- The android emulator is very low level, that is it emulates a hardware and then runs the normal software on top of it. Thus it has no idea of highler level protocols like TCP, it only emulates the network card.
- TCP is a protocol where all messages are acknowledged by the peer. If the emulator would have problems receiving messages it would probably also not receive the acknowledgements for the packets you send. But this would make further sends inside your application fail which is contrary to your statement that sending works.
- If there would be such a problem inside the emulator others would have noticed too.

Comment: Thank You But Are you sure "not receiving acknowledgements causes further sends fail so that server won't receive new messages"? All messages are delivered to the server, I check this in server side not in client side. But are you sure about that statement?

Comment: Yes, this is how TCP works. If the acknowledgment don't get back to the android kernel it will mark the connection as broken and further writes will fail.

Comment: Maybe acknowledgements are received but not other packets! I reviewed whole the code again and again but didn't find anything which causes the server to receive but the client(emulator) not to

Comment: If nothing except acknowledgments is received, then maybe nothing else was sent by the peer. The emulator emulates a network card which doesn't know anything about TCP, so it can not selectively block data and only let acknowledgments through. Why don't you simply try a web browser inside the emulator - if it can receive data then the problem is not inside the emulator but either at your sender application or your receiver application. You might also do a packet dump outside the emulator with wireshark or similar to see what data get exchanged on the wire.

Comment: Well The only way left is to use a packet sniffer. I'll check with wireShark and see what happens

Comment: Dude I checked it and wireshark confirmed that the packets are received and also the Listening-Thread is working and waiting for a packet. But BufferedReader and inputStream read function doesn't get anything

Comment: If this would be a problem of the emulator and not of your application, than neither a web browser nor mail would work inside the emulator and probably lots of people would complain about the broken emulator. So I still suggest its a problem of your application.

Comment: And also the acknowledgment is sent back to the server from the client BUT the InputStream (Also BufferedReader) does not read anything and 1 second time out occurs. I don't know what kind of problem is this?

Comment: Do web browsers use TCP sockets same as I do in my program? Also I keep the connection between peers alive for a long time but web browsers don't. anyway I'm nearly sure there is something wrong here with the emulator

Comment: Yes, web browsers use TCP. Web browser keep the connection also alive for some time and mail clients using IMAP keep it alive for much longer. And according to your description from the packet dump the connection is alive from the kernel side, so the problem is at the application layer.

Comment: I traced the codes And observed that The in.readLine blocks and doesn't read anything until time out and the loop call it again. well if this is my application's fault what do you think the problem can be? (Supposing that connection is alive and InputStream reads nothing)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make any assumptions of what your code is doing without seeing it and I don't want to dig through hundreds of lines of code. I suggest you try to reproduce the problem with a small and simple code first.

Comment: I tested on my friend's android tablet a few minutes ago and the app is working without this problem. So I'm more sure the problem is from the emulator.
Thank you Steffen. I'll try to install android x86 and use it instead of the default emulator.

Comment: I'm surprised. It would probably helpful if you could create a small code to reproduce the problem and file a bug.

Comment: Well the networking part of the project is complicated and big with so many threads and functions which control them. But I am not as much surprise as you. Because this is not the first time I experience problems with emulator. Also others report such problems time to time. But if I upload the app to google market I can inform you if you want. Just please give your email address (but of course there is much left to complete the project)